# light weight template engine for python

Tags: python, templating

Which is the simplest and light weight html templating engine in Python which I can use to generate customized email newsletters.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For a really minor templating task, Python itself isn't that bad. Example:

```
def dynamic_text(name, food):
    return """
    Dear %(name)s,
    We're glad to hear that you like %(food)s and we'll be sending you some more soon.
    """ % {'name':name, 'food':food}
```

In this sense, you can use string formatting in Python for simple templating. That's about as lightweight as it gets.

If you want to go a bit deeper, [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) is the most "designer friendly" (read: simple) templating engine in the opinion of many.

You can also look into Mako and Genshi. Ultimately, the choice is yours (what has the features you'd like and integrates nicely with your system).

Comment: I agree, a lot of times Python's formatting facilities are just what's needed. You can do something like `"Hello {foo}".format(foo="World")`. Also consider, Python `string` module: http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#template-strings

But once you begin to require some conditional or iterative logic in-template, you'll need something more substantial as suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 21):

Anything wrong with [string.Template](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings)? This is in the standard Python distribution and covered by [PEP 292](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0292/):

```
from string import Template

form=Template('''Dear $john,

I am sorry to imform you, $john, but you will not be my husband
when you return from the $theater war. So sorry about that. Your
$action has caused me to reconsider.

Yours [NOT!!] forever,

Becky

''')

first={'john':'Joe','theater':'Afgan','action':'love'}
second={'john':'Robert','theater':'Iraq','action':'kiss'}
third={'john':'Jose','theater':'Korean','action':'discussion'}

print form.substitute(first)
print form.substitute(second)
print form.substitute(third)
```

Comment: str.format() is much more powerful than string.Template, but as simple.

Comment: Does it support loops or conditionals?

Answer (score 0):

Searching for *tiny template Python* in Google turned up Titen, whose source code is only [5.5 kB](http://code.google.com/p/titen/source/browse/titen.py). Titen can do iteration over lists, which the built-in *str.format* can't.

[Mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/) claims to be lightweight, but it's relatively fat (>200 kB) compared to Titen. Jinja2 and Django Templates are also well over 100 kB.

Comment: Does Titen exist anymore?

Answer (score -3):

Give a try to python-micro-template:

https://github.com/diyism/python-micro-template

Usage example(kivy):

```
import python_micro_template
...
kvml=open('example_kivy_scrollview.kvml', 'r').read()
kvml=python_micro_template.tpl.parse(kvml)
grid=Builder.load_string(kvml)
...
```

Template example(kvml):

```
<:for i in range(30):#{#:>
Button:
    text: '<:=i:><:for j in range(6):#{#:><:=j:><:#}#:>'
    size: 480, 40
    size_hint: None, None
<:#}#:>
```

Comment: This project looks unmaintained as of 2022.  Last commit 9 years ago