# Return data from html file with variable

Tags: python

I have a python file like this :

```
data = "data is there"
with open('index.html', 'r+') as f:
  index = f.read()
  return index
```

My index.html is like this :

```
<html>'+data+'</html>
```

Actual Output

```
<html>'+data+'</html>
```

Wanted output

```
<html>data is there</html>
```

EDIT:
As specified in the comment, this answers my question : [light weight template engine for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406102/light-weight-template-engine-for-python)

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406102/light-weight-template-engine-for-python

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for